# Laravel chart with groupbyday

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, charts

i was trying to implement [Chart with Laravel](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) there i want to show my monthly collection which daily collection for that i used following Query

```
  $data = Transaction::select('transactions.updated_at', 
        DB::raw('sum(collected_today) as aggregate'))->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(transactions.updated_at)'))->get(); 

        $chart = Charts::database($data,'area', 'highcharts')
          ->preaggregated(true)
          ->title('Monthly Collection')
          ->elementLabel("Total")
          ->dateColumn('transactions.updated_at');
          ->groupByDay();
```

but in chart it shows nothing means blank space. in the documentation it says *To work with the GroupByYear, GroupByMonth, GroupByDay, lastByYear, lastByMonth & lastByDay you'll need the column created_at in the data rows.*

But i need to use the updated_at means yesterday dues can be collected today which will be consider as today's collection. How can i make it working with updated_at. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set [dateColumn()](https://erik.cat/projects/Charts/docs/5#database-charts) :

```
Charts::database($data,'area', 'highcharts')->dateColumn('updated_at');
```

Comment: I have updated my question with your solution. But it shows nothing in my chart. empty value. Should i make other changes?

Comment: please check your data in database and see if their any match. It would be better if you provide some sample data and explain us what you want to achieve